# Accessing Pdf file from Database using MVC4 Asp.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

I am stucked in a situation working from 2 days, tried searching many sites 
for the solution couldn't find anything including Stackoverflow,

**WHAT I NEED**

I am working on MVC, and I have a Byte array file which is already saved in database(SQL) and I need to access the file from database, and display it into PDF file, there is not Writable task to do, just Readable from database.

**WHAT I DID**

->Wrote Javascript to get the ID's of the give information.

->on click of "Download" button called method in JS, and made redirect to Controller with the ID's I need (which is good till now!!) (PIC 1)

->Generated Stored Procedure to access all column information based on the ID's (PIC 2)

[image]
[image]

> **ScannedResult** is the column where the value has been stored, and I need to access that file.

**WHAT I COULDN'T FIND**

-> Couldn't able to find a way to access that byte array and display into PDF!!

-> as in shown in PIC4, while debugging it shows the error message "Failed to convert parameter String to Int64", and I do know what does that error mean, I just want to give some more information here, the ID's I am getting is "**BigInt**" and I am passing it as **String**(see in Controller), Reason behind for this, there might be having multiple ID's in single shot, so using "," (PIC 3) in the middle of all ID's, so I have planned to convert into "String" or If any body have greater suggestion I am all yours to listen,

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE1**

[image]

```
Please help me to find out this issue, answers will be appreciated.
```

Comment: you are passing string while it accepts int as parameter

Comment: Hi even tried that(see New Pic) , converting it into int64 and this is what I got, or what am i Doing wrong , BTW above is part of my question, and I even need code in controller to access the byte array file to display...

Comment: string has comma in it to conversion failing, instead change db parameter to varchar

Comment: cannot because database is already using it in many places, and it is not the first page, have trouble accessing the data with "," my main concern in how to access the file ? in controller

Comment: you need to pass integer id if it is only one and need to pass as string if many ids comma seperated and use Varchar at db end then

Comment: Dear Sajjad, I am able to get what you are saying, i have implemented same concept in some places too with working condition, I have less worry about this string ID's, my many concern is about accessing the file from sql, would you have idea to get the file and display it into PDF,based on the ID in controller ??